# listview drag listener apply to all views in layout

Tags: android, listview, drag-and-drop

I have an app that uses the [this](https://github.com/ericharlow/TICEWidgets/tree/master/DragNDropList) library as a drag and drop activity to reorder items. 
I adjusted the item layout to have two images and text (instead of one image and the text), and I moved the image that they click to drag to the far right. My problem is now the first image has the drag listener attached to it. (And if I put the text first and then the two images second, the listener applies only to the text). Is there a way I can choose which element has the drag listener, or make all of the elements have it.

It seems like its just giving it to the first child of the layout. I tried to just put all three views in a linear layout hoping that the linear layout would have the listener, but it just bypassed that and went to the first element of that layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i found it. I tried putting an invisible image first that stretched the entire width of the view, but it still only applied to the left part of the view.

Then I did some more digging and found this code in the DragNDropListView.java file

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    final int x = (int) ev.getX();
    final int y = (int) ev.getY();  

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && x < this.getWidth()/4) {
        mDragMode = true;
    }
    ...
}
```

just change the `this.getWidth()/4` to `this.getWidth()` to have it use the entire view instead of the first 1/4

**EDIT: Do Not Do This If** the list you are reordering does not fit on the screen, if the entire width is used you cannot scroll down the list